# Remove line break from text in JavaScript (variable value from XSLT)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, search-results, xslt

I need get a variable value from **XSLT** in search result in SharePoint 2010. But this value is muti-lines text. When I add this variable value in JavaScript, the JS code cannot work, because the line break.
How can I remove line break from text ? Or remove them directely in XSLT ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to convert different objects to strings.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x1 = '<xsl:value-of select="$information"/>';

//The contents of this variable value
'To submit your request, plase contact Mr XX 


HR request (for HR only!!!)


           Warning : Offre available for people working in HR


  This request allows you to modify your account name.
Thank you';
//End of contents


var res = String(x1);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found how to modify the code. I change this

```
var x1 ='<xsl:value-of select="$information"/>';
```

To

```
var info = thisitem.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div');
var x=info[0].innerHTML;
```

"thisitem" is a variable value

It works!!!!